# Is there any resource related to symmetry notion?

Tags: symmetry, resource-recommendations

I am a second year physics student. I am following my regular classes and additionally trying to improve my mathematical tools. I am wondering whether is there any course or textbook about the symmetry notion and insights of it?

Comment: Many of the standard textbooks in math/phys will have chapter on elementary group theory.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful.  Prof. Sean Carroll recently put out a series on YouTube which covers a wide range of Physics topics, including symmetry:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCxacFBLHIY&list=PLrxfgDEc2NxZJcWcrxH3jyjUUrJlnoyzX&index=28

The focus is on conceptual/insightful understanding of the topics.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!